# Has someone made UIActionSheet (buttonIndex, delegate) more like UIButton (addTarget:action)?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I saw [this tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/marcoarment/status/25403513232171008) by Marco Armant:

> Subclassed `UIActionSheet w/target:action:userInfo:` on buttons to avoid delegates/buttonIndex. Didn't someone else do this? Can't find it.

I think that sounds like a great idea, but I wasn't able to find anyone's code that did this. Does anyone know of one, before I go do it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see my github for [`OHActionSheet`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAlertView-OHActionSheet).

It is implemented using blocks, so that you can use it this way, even without deporting the target/action code elsewere in your source code, the great advantage being that everything is located in the same place in your source code, and that you can use as many `OHActionSheets` as you want in the same controller

```
NSURL* anURL = ... // some URL (this is only as an example on using out-of-scope variables  in blocks)
[OHActionSheet showSheetInView:yourView
                         title:@"Open this URL?"
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
             otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Open",@"Bookmark",nil]
                    completion:^(OHActionSheet* sheet,NSInteger buttonIndex) {
   if (buttonIndex == sheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
     NSLog(@"You cancelled");
   } else {
     NSLog(@"You choosed button %d",buttonIndex);
     switch (buttonIndex-sheet.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
       case 0: // Open
         // here you can access the anURL variable even if this code is executed asynchrously, thanks to the magic of blocks!
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:anURL];
         break;
       case 1: // Bookmark
       default:
         // Here you can even embed another OHAlertView for example
         [OHAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Wooops"
                                 message:@"This feature is not available yet, sorry!"
                            cancelButton:@"Damn"
                            otherButtons:nil
                          onButtonTapped:nil]; // no need for a completion block here
         break;
     } // switch
   }
 }];
```

*[EDIT] Edited sample code to add more details and usage examples*

Comment: It looks good, but you still have to define the array of button titles, get those based on index, and then turn those into selectors, if you wanted to pass that action on. I was hoping for something that would be more like `UIButton`, where I would only have to define titles, selectors, and targets at one time.

Comment: One thing that I like about the blocks approach is that you can easily show subsequent action sheets via the same UIBarButtonItem, since you know it when you display the first one. (I don't know a good way of doing this with normal UIActionSheet.)

Comment: (The reason I would want to pass the actions on is to have an action sheet that I use in multiple view controllers that they all respond to.)

Comment: An example of a solution for that: you could define an `NSArray* btnDefs` containing NSDictionaries, each `NSDictionary` having a key `@"title"` and a key `@"selector"` for example. Then use the KVC facility using `[btnDefs valueForKey:@"title"]` for the `otherButtonTitles` parameter, and in the code of the completionBlock, use sthg like `NSString* selectorName = [[btnDefs objectAtIndex:buttonIndex-sheet.firstOtherButtonIndex] objectForKey:@"selector"];`, then `SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);` to get the selector and finally `[self performSelector:selector];` to execute it

Comment: Thx zekel for the edit, I updated the sample too to reflect the name change and added some more usage examples. Note that another advantage of using blocks is that you can access variables that are out of the scope of the asynchronous block being executed when the OHActionSheet button is tapped. See my edit and the case with `anURL`. Doubt you can have this advantage if you just associate one  target/action with each button ;)

Comment: Ended up using OHActionSheet/Script. They're really great. Thanks for sharing.